# Is the Whomping Willow enchanted?

Tags: harry-potter

There was a comment on another question that referred to the Whomping Willow as a semi-sentient plant.

Are the actions the Whomping Willow takes inherent to that species of plant or is it simply an enchanted willow tree?

I always thought the latter but I'm not sure if I am forgetting something mentioned in the books.

Comment: I believe when Ron and Harry crash the Ford Anglia into it in CoS, someone (Snape?) says something like "causing damage to a very rare species". I'm at work, so have no access to the book, but that may be a good place to start. (Wikia uses the word species, but uncited.)

Comment: FWIW, Snape says it is valuable, not rare.

Comment: @mikeazo aren't those inherently the same thing? Or at least related enough to not be worth the distinction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> "I noticed, in my search of the park, that considerable damage seems
>   to have been done to a very valuable Whomping Willow,"

This is the quote by Professor Snape mentioned in the comment

This is the quote by Lockhart

> "Just been showing Professor Sprout the right way to doctor a Whomping
>   Willow! But I don't want you running away with the idea that I'm
>   better at Herbology than she is! I just happen to have met several of
>   these exotic plants on my travels . . ."

So at least according to him they are a species of plant and so, probably how the one planted in Hogwarts behaves is in it's nature

But then again, it's Lockhart so we can't be certain.

Here's a forum discussion on the same topic: [The Whomping Willow](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aru0-eoakeR8J%3aalohomora.mugglenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=518%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk)

Comment: Ah, looks like I was wrong. Still quite suggestive, but definitely not definitive. Thanks!

Comment: I wish it was a more reliable source than Lockhart; but I think this is enough to imply that the Whomping Willow is a species.